# Infinite loop issue on window load

Tags: jquery

I am stuck with an issue, Creating a script which does change the currency according to country name. I have written the currency change code already which change the currency after change function trigger.(For now on below code I am just writing here location.reload() for refresh the page)

My issue is that, I want to select the currency according to Country name after window load first time BUT it is refreshing the page infinitely.I want to load the page only one time.

NOTE: I am here writing location.reload() for just understanding that my change function does refresh the page (Where I have already written the currency change code)

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
      var country = data.country_name;
      //alert(country);
      if (country=="Australia"){
        $("option[value='AUD']").attr('selected','selected').trigger('change');
      }
      });

      //change function
      $("#edit-selected-currency").change(function(){
       location.reload();
      });

      });
    </script> 
</head>
    <body>
      <select id="edit-selected-currency" name="selected_currency" >
      <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
      <option value="INR" >INR</option>
      <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you reloading the page?

Comment: I am reloading the page to change the currency thats why I here only wrote page refresh code not full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
      var country = data.country_name;
      //alert(country);
      if (country=="Australia"){
        $("option[value='AUD']").attr('selected','selected').trigger('change');
//change function
      $("#edit-selected-currency").change(function(){
       location.reload();
      });
      }
      });



      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `trigger('change')` this is a solution because you are reload page on change event.

BUT, still your need to fire trigger event you can do, you can detect triggered event as mentioned below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function (data) {
        var country = data.country_name;
        //alert(country);
        if (country=="Australia"){
            $("option[value='AUD']").attr('selected','selected').trigger('change','triggered');
        }
    });

    //change function
    $("#edit-selected-currency").change(function(e,x){
        if(x=='triggered')
        {
            // it is from trigger 
        }
        else
        {
            // here x is undefined
            location.reload();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, The change function which I have written only works after page refresh thats why I trigger the change function after window load. My only issue is that page it is refreshing the page infinite time

Comment: yes, your code seems when country is AUD it will going infinite time through trigger which you have fired on change in success reponse.

Comment: I want to execute the change function after window load but only once.Hope here I am making some sense.

Answer (score -1):

Removing `trigger('change');` will solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you, but I know it already. The change function which I have written only works after page refresh thats why I trigger the change function after window load. My only issue is that page it is refreshing the page infinite time.